# Count how often pairs of values in a dataframe appear in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1` that looks like this:

```
d1 = {'way_id': [4, 3, 1, 8, 5, 2, 7, 9, 6], 'source': [12, 11, 13, 15, 19, 16, 18, 14, 17], 'target': [28, 24, 25, 21, 24, 29, 27, 22, 23]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

way_id  source  target
4       12      28
3       11      24
1       13      25
8       15      21
5       19      24
2       16      29
7       18      27
9       14      22
6       17      23
```

And a second dataframe `df2` that looks like this:

```
d2 = {'node1': [11, 13, 18, 17, 27], 'node2': [24, 29, 27, 25, 18]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2

node1   node2
11      24
13      29
18      27
17      25
27      18
```

Now I would like to evaluate how often the value pairs per row in the columns `node1` and `node2` in `df2` occur in the rows of the columns of `source` and `target` in `df1`. The order is irrelevant. That's why the desired output should be like this:

```
way_id  source  target  count
4       12      28      0
3       11      24      1
1       13      25      0
8       15      21      0
5       19      24      0
2       16      29      0
7       18      27      2
9       14      22      0
6       17      23      0
```

I'm newish to python and struggle how to deal with comparing values in multiple columns between two dataframes. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert values to `frozenset`s, use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df2[['node1','node2']].agg(frozenset, axis=1).value_counts()
df1['count'] = df1[['source','target']].agg(frozenset, axis=1).map(s).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)

   way_id  source  target  count
0       4      12      28      0
1       3      11      24      1
2       1      13      25      0
3       8      15      21      0
4       5      19      24      0
5       2      16      29      0
6       7      18      27      2
7       9      14      22      0
8       6      17      23      0
```

Comment: Is there any performance benefit to use `.fillna(0).astype(int)` over `fillna(0, downcast='infer')`?

Comment: @SayandipDutta - yop, it is better, but not alwyas working (but if working then it is better)

Comment: @jezrael - what if the order in which these values occur would be relevant? Can I still use `frozenset` in that case?

Comment: @winecity - hmmm, I think then need change `frozenset` to `tuple`